# Can't build matplotlib from source on Windows 64 (Py3.6) - png error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-2010, matplotlib, build

From much research online, it seems that installing matplotlib from source on Windows is not straightforward and many have issues. While many SO posts have solved problems, I'm still having an issue that I can't seem to solve.

After cloning the matplotlib repository from GitHub, I followed instructions from the matplotlib website to install it, and get the following output log when I try to run python setup.py develop:

```html
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.0.2+4901.g7dc7a325c]
                python: yes [3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul
                        20 2017, 12:30:02) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.13.1]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.10.0]
              dateutil: yes [dateutil was not found. It is required for date
                        axis support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
backports.functools_lru_cache: yes [Not required]
          subprocess32: yes [Not required]
                  pytz: yes [pytz was not found. pip/easy_install may
                        attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip/easy_install may
                        attempt to install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [Using local version for testing]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.15]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.20]
                 latex: yes [version MiKTeX 2.9]
               pdftops: yes [version 0.55.0]

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * png * Please check http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net
                        * /packages/libpng.htm for instructions to install
                        * png
```

The issue seems to be libpng.

I tried using the recommended scipt for Windows (https://github.com/jbmohler/matplotlib-winbuild), but got a VS2010 not found error. When I tried to install this, the Microsoft Python Tools website suggests Py3.6 64-bit doesn't support earlier than VS2015 version.

I also tried install libpng manually using a binary from: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm
but I get the same error even after this installs successfully.

Is there a fix for this please? Or does anything have a good reference for how to install matplotlib for Windows - it seems that a definitive and comprehensive guide here would be very useful for the community, as there are many questions with users struggling with this!

Any help welcomed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build matplotlib 3.1.1 from source with Visual Studio 2017 using [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/bjoas/933e8433455ac69ed3833d4ee2c6d952).

One of the tricks is that some libraries needs to be renamed, like `libpng.lib -> png.lib` and `zlib.lib -> z.lib`.